# UICollectionView + NSFetchedResultsController in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift3, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my current project I integrated a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `UICollectionView` which works fine. Currently I try to upgrade the project to Swift 3 and Xcode 8 which causes the following error message

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread.
```

I'm using a `BlockOperation` array to queue up the changes to the `UICollectionView`. Here is an example of how I insert a new item.

```
self.blockOperations.append(BlockOperation(block: {
   collectionView?.insertItems( at: [newIndexPath!])
}))
```

This is my current implementation of `controllerDidChangeContent`

```
var blockOperations = [BlockOperation]()

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    if self.shouldReloadCollectionView {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({    
        for operation in self.blockOperations {
            OperationQueue.current?.addOperation(operation)
        }
        }, completion: { (completed) in
            print(completed)
    })
}
```

Has anyone implemented `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `UICollectionView` in Swift 3 an can help me with this?

Comment: hey, maybe that will help?  - https://gist.github.com/nazywamsiepawel/e88790a1af1935ff5791c9fe2ea19675

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Pawel, your Gist was very helpful. I forked it and updated it to fully support `Swift 3` and `iOS10`. Since it doesn't solved the problem with updating the `UICollectionView` from a background thread.

The error is caused by updating the `UICollectionView` from a background thread.

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread.
```

To get a combination of `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UICollectionView` working you have to wrap every update of the `collectionView` object inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // i.e. insertion of new items                          
    this.collectionView!.insertItems(at: [newIndexPath!])
}
```

Here is a link to the full updated [Gist](https://gist.github.com/nor0x/c48463e429ba7b053fff6e277c72f8ec)