# How to make UICollectionView work with NSFetchResultController

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm looking for a way to make UICollectionView work with NSFetchResultsController. I've looked for a solution, found a post from Ash Furrow but it wasn't in swift 3. I'm stuck when you implement the two functions from the controller. Which are these 2 below.

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

}
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

}
```

When I was working with UITableViews, I was able to put tableView.beginUpdates and tableView.endUpdates and move along. However, when trying to use collectionViews I don't get begin or end updates. I don't have the faintest idea on how to make UICollectinView work with NSFetchResultsController. Would appreciate any help provided. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView + NSFetchedResultsController in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024166/uicollectionview-nsfetchedresultscontroller-in-swift-3)

Comment: Check the GIST link in the duplicate answer for a full code.

Comment: Hey sneak this post helped. However, inside the code, there is a line of code that I'm confused. It's where it say self.shouldReloadCollectionView = true. Is that collectionView.reloadData()?

Comment: It is a simple BOOL defined variable that you can set in the class you want.

Comment: Ah okay. Would you set it to false first or just cast it as a Bool?

Comment: Also what is the deinit method for? I'm looking at snippets of code and they don't have the willChangeContent func only the didChangeContent. Why? Sorry for asking a lot of question. Just want to understand what is going on.

Comment: You need to read the basics of NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate and https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller, I can't unfortunately give you more support, if you have questions you need to Google it, unless it is something fit for SO. Also we can't use the comment section as a chat. But what you are trying to achieve is not something simple, it is advanced and you need some knowledge to what you are doing in the first place. Good luck!